# Compensating for pitch, roll and yaw in X, Y and Z(translational) values

Tags: c++, trigonometry, euler-angles

Firstly, I understand this is not really a programming question but I believe that some of you here will understand what I'm trying to obtain. I'm a radiation Therapist and my research revolves around treating cancer patients with radiation and ensuring that their position is as accurate as possible during treatment. Rotation of the body(pitch, roll and Yaw) is a common problem and our machine is unable to correct for this. Could you please help advice a formula that will be able to convert the rotational values to the x y and z planes (our machine can only correct errors in this planes) so we can compensate for the errors?

Pitch is the rotation (clockwise)  about the x axis 
Roll is the rotation (clockwise) about the y axis 
And yaw is the rotation (clockwise) about the z axis

Where x is the plane denoting left to right, 
Y is the plane denoting cranio-caudal (or superior-inferior)
And z is the plane denoting up and down

I hope my question makes sense and I really hope you guys could help me out. Is there a formula for this? Please and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yaw, pitch and roll can be represented with a rotation matrix corresponding to the xyz representation. So, given the rotation angles for all three of them, you can compose the three rotation matrices to get the linear transform they represent. See [here](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node102.html) for the algebra worked out.